# PostgreSQL inherit postgres's privileges

Tags: postgresql, user-roles

I followed the doc to use `createuser xxx -g postgres -i` to create an account as a member of postgres, but it seems that the new user xxx doesn't have any privileges of postgres, such as create user and create db. Why is that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [the docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/role-membership.html):

> The role attributes `LOGIN`, `SUPERUSER`, `CREATEDB`, and `CREATEROLE` can be thought of as special privileges, but they are never inherited as ordinary privileges on database objects are. You must actually `SET ROLE` to a specific role having one of these attributes in order to make use of the attribute.

Your user has the permission to assume the role of `postgres`, but it doesn't inherit the [permission to create a user or database](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/role-attributes.html). You'd need to grant (`ALTER ROLE`, actually) that explicitly. (Though the user could grant it themselves).